# Java : given a list of object that has range of dates find two objects whose end month is closest to current date month

Tags: java

**List of dates are as below (The list can be in any order):**
3-Jan to 31-Mar, 2-Apr to 30-Jun, 1-Jul to 30-Sep, 4-Oct to 31-Dec

Current Date is: 19-Feb

**Can someone please help me with the logic?**

**My approach is:**

if(the given date should be greater than start date and less than end date){//this gives current quarter}else if(difference of the month of current date from the end date of each object should be less than or equal to 5)

i am hard coding the condition less than 5, which may break if in future the range of date will be of 4 months

**Second approach is:**

we can sort the list in ascending order and can get the current quarter index by comparing with current date and the next quarter will be of next index. But the complexity will be more.

I tried below code, but it gives only current quarter date. I am not able to get next quarter considering there would be only 3 objects and current date month is feb.

public static List getCurrentQtrOffr(List detail,Date currentDate) throws ParseException{

```
    int currentQuarter = 9999, diff1;
    int nextquarter = 9999, diff2;
    Detail detail1;
    Detail detail2;
    Detail detail3 = null;
    Detail detail4 = null;
    Iterator<Detail> iterator = detail.iterator();

    List<Detail> list = new ArrayList<Detail>();

    while(iterator.hasNext()){
        detail1 = iterator.next();      
        diff1 = getDiff(currentDate,detail1.startTime());

        if(diff1>0){

        if(iterator.hasNext()){
        detail2 = iterator.next();
        }else{
        detail2 = null;
        }

        if(detail2 != null){
        diff2 = getDiff(currentDate,detail2.startTime());

        if(diff1 < diff2 ){
            if(currentQuarter > diff1){
            nextquarter = currentQuarter;
            currentQuarter = diff1;
            //how to assign detail3 before updating it with next minimum value, as if there will be only 3 object and flow comes in this if block then detail4 will be null
            detail4=detail3;
            detail3=detail1;
            }else if(nextquarter > diff1){
            nextquarter = diff1;
            detail4=detail1;
            }
        }else{

            if(currentQuarter > diff2){
                nextquarter = currentQuarter;
                currentQuarter = diff2;
                detail4=detail3;
                detail3=detail1;
            }else if(nextquarter > diff2){
                nextquarter = diff2;
                detail4=detail1;
            }
        }           
    }else{
        if(currentQuarter > diff1){
            nextquarter = currentQuarter;
            currentQuarter = diff1;
            detail4=detail3;
            detail3=detail1;
        }else if(nextquarter > diff1){
            nextquarter = diff1;
            detail4=detail1;
        }
    }
    }else{
        System.out.println("skipped "+diff1);
    }
    }
    list.add(detail3);
    list.add(detail4);
    return list;
}
```

Comment: what is wrong with question that it is marked in negative?

Comment: cannot use calendar as date range is subject to change.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I'm guessing they downvoted because you didn't try anything. You should post what you've tried. Read: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: My approach is: if(the given date should be greater than start date and less than end date){//this gives current quarter}else if(difference of the month of current quarter from the end date of each object should be less than or equal to 5)

Comment: Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Ok now i posted my approach but in that i am hard coding the condition less than 5, which may break if in future the range of date will be of 4 months.

Comment: Another approach was that we can sort the list in ascending order and can get the current quarter index by comparing with current date and the next quarter will be of next index. But the complexity will be more.

Comment: i posted my approach but why people are rating in negative, instead they can comment if they want any thing from my side.

Comment: @Rehan It is your responsibility to understand the rules for this site.  Please visit the [help] and especially read [ask] to learn how to use this site effectively.  Posting a question that is off-topic and then complaining when it is downvoted is not the way things work here.  Also, you should not post clarifications in comments, [edit] your original post to include updated information.

Comment: I improved it and added the approach i tried. Really looking for help as have some time constraint.

Comment: Please edit your question instead of adding comments. It's hard to read with all the comments, which may or may not be shown initially. Also clean up your code, the formatting makes it hard to read.

Answer (score 1):

If the periods are mutually exclusive (not overlapping) the you simply check for the first occurrence where:

- The target is equal to or later than the start, *and…*
- The target is before the stop.

This logic follows the Half-Open approach commonly used in date-time work where the beginning is *inclusive* while the ending is *exclusive*.

A shorter way of saying "the target is equal to or later than the start" is "not before start". The exclamation mark `!` means `not` in Java syntax.

```
Boolean periodContainsTarget = ( ! target.isBefore( start ) ) && target.isBefore( stop ) ;
```

The above logic would be used with `LocalDate` if you meant date with a year. If you literally meant a month and day without a year, use the `MonthDay` class. The logic works for both.

Use [`Period`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Period.html) class to represent the span of time between a pair of `LocalDate` objects. See [Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/iso/period.html).

You might also find useful the [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html) class in the [ThreeTen-Extra](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project that supplements java.time.

Comment: Thanks for replying! the logic you mentioned will help in obtaining first closest quarter. But I need the second closest quarter too.

Comment: Use [`Period`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Period.html) class to represent the span of time between a pair of `LocalDate` objects. See [Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/iso/period.html).

Comment: I am not using Java 8 . Its my bad I was making simple logic complex, instead of iterating two objects at a time when I made it to one it started working. Something like getting two min values from a list or array. Thanks Basil for your time!

Comment: @Rehan Much of java.time is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in the ThreeTen-Backport project. Further adapted to Android in the ThreeTenABP project. Well worth adding to your app as the legacy classes are notoriously troublesome.